# How to simplify code written with switch in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

how can I simplify this switch? Is there an easier way to write a switch like that? Or to return as in the switch depending on the 5 cases I have?

```
data() {
        return {
            stepOneIsCompleted: false,
            stepTwoIsCompleted: false,
            stepThreeIsCompleted: false,
            stepFourIsCompleted: false,
            stepFiveIsCompleted: false,
        };
    },
```

```
updateViewEditVisibility(step, status) {
            switch (step) {
            case 1:
                status === 200 ? this.stepOneIsCompleted = true : this.stepOneIsCompleted = false;
                break;

            case 2:
                status === 200 ? this.stepTwoIsCompleted = true : this.stepOneIsCompleted = false;
                break;

            case 3:
                status === 200 ? this.stepThreeIsCompleted = true : this.stepOneIsCompleted = false;
                break;

            case 4:
                status === 200 ? this.stepFourIsCompleted = true : this.stepOneIsCompleted = false;
                break;

            case 5:
                status === 200 ? this.stepFiveIsCompleted = true : this.stepOneIsCompleted = false;
                break;
            }
        },
```

It should be mentioned that I will send those values as props.
Couldn't I make an array for example and look in it according to step and assign a value to it?

Comment: Make this step..... an array?

Comment: or just use `step` and only increment it if *completed*, instead of `v-if="stepOneIsCompleted"` have `v-if="step === 1"`

Answer (score 2):

```
data() {
    return {
        stepCompleted: [
            false,  //stepOneIsCompleted
            false,  //stepTwoIsCompleted
            false,  //...
            false,
            false
        ]
    }
}

...

updateViewEditVisibility(step, status) {
    this.stepCompleted[step] = status === 200;
}
```